# DataFrame Output Not Rending Inline as DT after R Upgrade

Tags: r, dataframe, dt, rnotebook

I'm running Windows 10 and recently upgraded from R 3.4.4 to 3.5.0 using the installr package.  I use R Notebooks exclusively for all my R activities and love how dataframe (and similar objects) are rendered inline at DT (datatables). Unfortunately after my upgrade data frames are no longer rendered inline as DTs. How do I fix this issue?

Below is an example output.

[image: Example]

Comment: This seems to have been filed as an issue here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1331

Comment: Thank you for the info. That didn't come up in any of my 100+ searches.